# How to convert ingresdate to timestamp (time elapsed since 1970)?

Tags: sql, ingres

I have Ingres DB and a table with timestamp column (seconds since 01/01/1970). I need to find all entries which happened today. Possible solution is:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date(_date(timestamp)) = date('today')
```

However, converting every timestamp into `ingresdate` is not the most efficient and I would like to just compare integers (i.e. `timestamp > x() AND timestamp < x() + 86400`)

Is there a way to convert `date('today')` into timestamp? I cannot find anything about it in ingress documentation.

Answer (score -1):

For conversion purpose, have you tried

```
 TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE)
```

or

```
TIMESTAMP(DATE '2015-04-08')
```

or perhaps use the DATE_TRUNC() function?

Comment: `TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE)`, `timestamp(date('today'))` and `date('today')` return exactly the same value: `2015-04-09 00:00:00.0`

Comment: sorry i'm a bit confused, you wanted to convert date to timestamp right? so how about:
    `SELECT * FROM table WHERE your_timestamp_column = TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE)`?

Comment: Have you read my question? My timestamp column has nothing to do with `ingresdate`: `Function '=' is not defined for arguments of type 'integer' and 'ingresdate'. Explicitly convert its arguments to the desired type(s).`

Comment: Sorry, i skiped that part about seconds.
Well, have you tried `SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM date('today'))` ?